# How to produce a 32-character SHA1?

Tags: c#

I am using this code to generate a sha1 hash but the output is 40 characters long.

How can I produce one that is only 32 characters long?

```
using (SHA1 shaHash = SHA1.Create())  
{  
  byte[] bytes = shaHash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawData));  
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();  
  for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)  
  {  
    builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));  
  }  

  return builder.ToString();  
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1 : _"SHA-1 (Secure Hash Algorithm 1) is a cryptographic hash function which takes an input and produces a 160-bit (20-byte) hash value"_ (i.e. 40 hex characters). At a guess: you're really dealing with MD5, OR you need to discard the last 4 bytes.

Comment: @llama thanks for replying. when processing warc files, there is this line: WARC-Block-Digest: sha1:Z6W6WEQQQICP5WA7OWB2SS75WLK4K7Y3. When I count, it's 32 characters. Should I discard the last 4 bytes? If so, how?

Comment: If my guess is correct re discarding bytes, `bytes.Length - 4` in your loop would do the trick. Perhaps you could provide sample input (base64 encoded) and resultant hash so that we can figure out how you're getting 32 characters.

Comment: @Llama: this would be 40 characters in the hex encoding. Other encodings (base64, base32) could produce less characters.

Comment: @kylie the hash you're showing there is not hex encoded, but your code uses hex.

Comment: https://iipc.github.io/warc-specifications/specifications/warc-format/warc-1.0/#warc-block-digest would suggest this is base32.

Comment: (That would also fit with it being 160 bits, with each character encoding 5 bits.

Comment: thanks everyone. been at it for hours.

Comment: @Wiktor Oh, I didn't look closely at Kylie's hash. I was just going off the C# code being hex.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Base32 implementation in a blog entry on [https://learn.microsoft.com/](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/cloudpfe/base32-encoding-and-decoding-in-c). There is no built-in ToBase32String method in Convert.

The formatting of this blog entry is very destroyed, I restored the formatting of this class:

```cs
// Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/cloudpfe/base32-encoding-and-decoding-in-c
public class Base32Encoder
{
    private const string Base32AllowedCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567";

    public string Encode(byte[] input, bool addPadding = true)
    {
        if (input == null || input.Length == 0)
        { return string.Empty; }
        var bits = input.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'))
            .Aggregate((a, b) => a + b)
            .PadRight((int)(Math.Ceiling((input.Length * 8) / 5d) * 5), '0');
        var result = Enumerable.Range(0, bits.Length / 5)
            .Select(i => Base32AllowedCharacters.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(bits.Substring(i * 5, 5), 2), 1))
            .Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
        if (addPadding)
        { result = result.PadRight((int)(Math.Ceiling(result.Length / 8d) * 8), '='); }
        return result;
    }

    public byte[] Decode(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        { return Array.Empty<byte>(); }
        return ToByteArray(input);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a Base32 string into the corresponding byte array, using 5 bits per character.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">The Base32 String</param>
    /// <returns>A byte array containing the properly encoded bytes.</returns>
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        { return new byte[0]; }
        var bits = input.TrimEnd('=').ToUpper()
            .ToCharArray()
            .Select(c => Convert.ToString(Base32AllowedCharacters.IndexOf(c), 2).PadLeft(5, '0'))
            .Aggregate((a, b) => a + b); var result = Enumerable.Range(0, bits.Length / 8)
            .Select(i => Convert.ToByte(bits.Substring(i * 8, 8), 2)).ToArray();
        return result;
    }
}
```

You can use this to create your hash:

```cs
using (SHA1 shaHash = SHA1.Create())
{
    byte[] bytes = shaHash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawData));
    var encoder = new Base32Encoder();
    return encoder.Encode(bytes, false);
}
```

**I can't prove this implementation of Base32**, so please check the values with some existing hashes.